# How to change label when text to speech task has finished reading in swift 3

Tags: swift, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I want the button btnSpeak to get changed automatically when the passage is completed reading. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {

        newsDetailView.btnSpeak.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "VolumeOFF"), for: UIControlState())

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you put a `print` statement in that function or add a breakpoint, does that function even get called? Lots of possible causes for this.

Comment: Yeah the function didFinish not getting called.. How to resolve it

Comment: Are you sure you set the `delegate` of your `AVSpeechSynthesizer` before you called `speak`?